# setting gradient for different buttons

Tags: android, xml

I am using an xml file with following code to set gradient and ripple for one of my buttons as soon as my app icon gets clicked.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:color="#c20586">
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient android:angle="135" android:startColor="#FFFF66" 
                  android:endColor="#000000" />
       </shape>
     </item>
```

My question is:
I have 6 such buttons. Is it a good practice to have 6 different xml files(I need different colours for each of them)?

If not, how to do it with single xml file? My best guess is in oncreate in java , but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code if you would like.

Create the button in your XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

From there you can do this...

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    int[] colors = {Color.parseColor("#008000"), Color.parseColor("#ADFF2F")};

    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

    gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(0f);

    button2.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```

Resource: https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/01/android-button-gradient-color.html

Comment: all i get is gradient rectangles...I need rounded buttns with nice ripple effect

Comment: Are you able to show me a screenshot of your ripple effect? EDIT: Or do you mean the stock effect when a button is pressed?

Comment: unable to capture the screenshot while ripple happens. When I press the button, my chosen colour ripple shows up. Its not the stock effect.

Comment: basically  button2.setBackground(gradientDrawable); overrides the background(ripple) set I did in xml.

Comment: yeah, which makes sense as to why. I don't have much knowledge of the ripple stuff, I never used it... sorry.

Comment: @JyotiGulati but I can tell you, in order to do the radius, you can do gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(NUMBER_HERE);

Comment: yea radius can be set, but ripple is main design spec.